# find specific column and clean all rows under it

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet with a random amount of columns and rows (amount of columns/rows changes every time, as well as the location of each column) where I need to find a certain column with title "Course Info", and then use the CLEAN function on all rows / cells in that column (except for the title row ofcourse).

I have the code for the clean function:

```
Set Rng = ShData.Range("AB2:AB" & LastRow)

For Each cell In Rng
    cell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(cell.Value)
Next cell
```

Problem here is that Rng is set to column AB, which isn't always that column. I have also made a LastRow & LastCol code to count the amount of rows and columns, but beyond this I'm stuck.

```
LastRow = ShData.Range(2, Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = ShData.Range(1, Cols.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [WorksheetFunction.Match method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.WorksheetFunction.Match) to get the column number.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim Col As Double
    On Error Resume Next 'next line throws error if "Course Info" was not found
    Col = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Course Info", ws.Rows(1), 0)
    On Error GoTo 0 'always re-activate error reporting

    If Col <> 0 Then 'only do it if "Course Info" was found
        Dim Cell As Range
        For Each Cell In ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, Col), ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp))
            Cell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(Cell.Value)
        Next Cell
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: On your approach you could declare `Col As Variant` and get rid of the `On Error` so you can use `Application.Match` and finally `If Not IsError(Col)` right?

Comment: @Damian yes, you could. Whatever you prefer to use. The idea and result should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

    Dim Rng As Range, Col As Long, cell As Range, LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long

    With ShData
        LastRow = .Range(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        LastCol = .Range(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Col = .Rows(1).Find("Course Info").Column 'this is to find the column number
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(2, Col), .Cells(LastRow, Col))
    End With

    For Each cell In Rng
        cell = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(cell)
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah... I copied his code, then I realized it was all wrong, already sorted.

Comment: LastRow and LastCol should be Cells, not Range. Find is the way to go, but worth checking first the term is found before using the column property to avoid errors, and usually worth specifying more arguments.

Comment: @Damian note that `.Cells.Find("Course Info")` searches in the whole sheet and not only in the header row. You could reduce search time a lot and make it more stable if you reduce it to `Rows(1).Find("Course Info")` • Also you need to define the `LookAt` parameter otherwise this is randomly `xlWhole` or `xlPart` (Excel uses whatever was used before by VBA or user interface. It has no default!).

Comment: @Pᴇʜ - I suppose the header might not be on row 1.

Comment: @SJR why? The OP used `"AB2:AB" & LastRow` to `Clean` data that means the header can only be in row 1 since data starts at 2.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ - I don't know, but surely it must be a possibility, which Find would cover.

Comment: on the code:
`LastRow = .Range(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).row`
I get error Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed

Comment: to add to the comment, I defined ShData this way:
`Dim ShData As Worksheet
'define Wb1 + Sh's
    Set Wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ShData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")`

Previously I used `Set ShData = WB1.Sheets("Data")`, but as I got the error too then I thought I'd change it to the code of @Pᴇʜ

Comment: Never mind previous comments, found out it was due to a typo in the title that I made in part Col = ..."Course Info").column, thanks all for the great help!